# Установка Collabora / Libreoffice online

Tags: libre-office

Здравствуйте. Установила Nextcloud, хотела прикрутить к нему collabora/CODE по [данной инструкции](https://nextcloud.com/collaboraonline/), но к сожалению наткнулась на проблему с сертификатами. Не могу найти нигде нормально разъяснения по данному вопросу, что и как надо сделать?

Answer (score 4):

Здравствуйте.
В nextcloud+collabora проблемы с сертификатами встречаются в нескольких местах. Мне удалось все настроить на самоподписанных сертификатах. Попробую описать свои "грабли":

- При открытии раздела office (http://nextcloud-server/index.php/apps/richdocuments/index) в браузере, возникает сообщение: "Collabora Online: SSL certificate is not installed....". Это лечится командой в шелле:

  $ cat collabora-online.local.crt.pem >> /var/www/nextcloud/resources/config/ca-bundle.crt
- При попытке открыть документ на редактирование, может появиться сообщение: "Не удаётся установить соединение с сайтом.". Лечится следующим образом:

  1. В новой закладке браузера (у меня яндекс-браузер) открываем ссылку ниже сообщения об ошибке. У меня это - https://collabora-online.local:8043/loleaflet/1.8.3/loleaflet.html . Далее появляется сообщение "Соединение с этим сервером небезопасно". Добавляем в список исключений.
  2. Возвращаемся к ссылке редактирования документа. Все заработало.

(Более или менее) Полное описание настройки Collabora Online - http://wown.ucoz.ru/blog/nastrojka_nextcloud_10_dlja_raboty_s_collabora_online/2016-11-25-68